# Почему в файле выгрузки прайс-листа магазина в Яндекс.Маркет в name и description одна и та же информация?

Tags: битрикс, seo

Есть сгенерированный битриксом файл выгрузки прайс-листа в Яндекс.Маркет, но почему-то в name и description выводиться однв и та же информация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в CMS description установлен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть ошибка? Куда смотреть?

Comment: В том что для Яндекс.Маркета используется поле описание товара, а не мета-тэг, хоть бы описание формата на сайте Маркета почитали что-ли для начала.

Comment: Вас понял, верно, ошибся. А как в моем случае тогда попадает в description тоже самое, что и в name? Как в битриксе указывается то, что будет передано в description/name?

Comment: где в CMS определено может быть что пишется в name, а что в description?

Comment: Почитайте пользовательскую документацию для начала прежде чем лезть куда-то.